# Show transaction for year

Tags: mysql, sql, rollup

Where the roll up has total '500', i would like for the results to show 'Grand Total' instead of where it is currently showing 'null'

Also, i am unsure how i can add a WHERE clause to view only transactions that were processed during 2018?

Any ideas? Thank you

```
select date_format(TRANSACTION_DATE, '%M') AS MONTH, 
SUM(SALES_AMOUNT) TOTAL
FROM SALES
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(TRANSACTION_DATE, '%M') WITH ROLLUP

January 160.00
June    100.00
May     240.00
Null    500.00
```

Comment: You could use `coalesce()` or `ifnull()` function to replace the null values

Comment: instead off `date_format(TRANSACTION_DATE, '%M')` you also can use `MONTH(TRANSACTION_DATE)`.. For the WHERE you can use `WHERE YEAR(TRANSACTION_DATE) = 2018`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8647e/4

```
SELECT 
isnull(datename(month, [Date1]), 'Total'),
SUM([Amount])
FROM Table1
GROUP BY datename(month , [Date1]) WITH ROLLUP
```

Result:

```
|         |     |
|---------|-----|
| January | 160 |
|    June | 100 |
|     May | 240 |
|   Total | 500 |
```

Comment: That returns the Null to 'May' for some reason?

Comment: January 160.00
June 100.00
May 240.00
May 500.00